# In a weather forecast API, should the city be a parameter or a URI

Tags: rest, api

I have observed multiple weather APIs(Yahoo, Open weather etc.) are using the "city" or the location as a parameter:

`GET  http://apibaseurl?city=sunnyvale`

as opposed to `GET  http://apibaseurl/city/sunnyvale`.

What are the design advantages of using the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://apibaseurl?city=sunnyvale
```

This URI has a query part that is an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` document of key value pairs.  HTML form processing supports this, which means that you can easily represent this pattern, and allow clients using general purpose web browsers to specify a particular value that they may be interested in.

There are [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) that allow you to copy parameters into path segments as well; but HTML doesn't have that capability available natively.